# Azure firewall log analytics. How to find Internal network traffic use network rule

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I check the network traffic in Azure firewall log analytics. I can see the different source IP addresses and port also has target IP address and port. But I can't see the internal network traffic in the same virtual network. For example, use jump box VM ssh to workload VM. Suppose I can see the jump box and workload network traffic. But I can't see that happen on my firewall log analytics. I want to know how to show all network traffic include the internal network. Thanks.

I follow this Azure Firewall log analytics samples and network rule log data query:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/log-analytics-samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure virtual network usually is secured with the [security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview). To view network traffic in a virtual network, you could check the [NSG flow logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-nsg-flow-logging-overview).

The NSG flow logs allow you to view information about **ingress and egress IP traffic** through a network security group. You can analyze flow logs and gain insights into your network traffic using [traffic analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/traffic-analytics).